# PostgreSQL OR condition not executing if one of them is true

Tags: postgresql, retool

My 2nd 'and' is throwing an error. I'm checking to see if either: 1.) dateRange1.value.start does not exist OR 2.) dateRange1.value.start is >= my job_start variable. #2 works when I have a value present in dateRange1.value.start, but when it's empty (ie; !dateRange1.value.start), I'm getting a "invalid input syntax for type date" error. The same exact type of statement works directly above where I'm checking the jobNameFilter.value. Why is this causing issues for my dateRange1.value.start?

```
SELECT
  id,
  user_id, 
  job_name,
  job_start,
  job_end
from jobs
where ({{ !jobNameFilter.value }} or lower(job_name) like {{ '%' + jobNameFilter.value.toLowerCase() + '%' }})
  and ({{ !dateRange1.value.start }} or date(job_start) >= {{ dateRange1.value.start }})
  and user_id = {{loginSuccessID.value}}
order by job_start;
```

Comment: job_start is a timestamp with no timezone. i'm using date() to only extract the date (but not time) from job_start. I'm not getting this error when there is a date present in dateRange1.value.start, which makes me think that statement itself works fine?

Comment: Ah, got it. Could you post an example of `dateRange1.value.start`?

Comment: Sure thing: "2022-11-01"

Comment: I think the problem is that PostgreSQL doesn't short circuit ands or ors, and your empty values must be being output as empty strings. Empty strings can be concatenated no problem, like on your first line, but not turned into dates, like on the second line.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense. Thanks for the response. I guess I'll find a way to pre-populate the dates on initial load so they always have a value.

Comment: What is `!dateRange1.value.start` actually doing? In other words what is it resolving to in the query that hits the database?

Comment: It's resolving to true or false based on if dateRange1.value.start exists. For what it's worth, I'm doing all of this in Retool

Comment: ` and ({{ !dateRange1.value.start }}` is not valid SQL, so it must be rewritten to something else. In SQL I could see(if I am following correctly) doing something like: `AND NULLIF(start, '') IS NULL ...`